# Export DataTables return [object Object] value

Tags: datatable, datatables

I want to export my datatable as CSV file. Unfortunately the Order History returns [object Object] value in CSV File. I have tried by looking this forum https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/50304/datatable-is-showing-object-object-in-columns#Comment_133450 but I'm not sure how should apply on my code.

Below the csv file, that give output [object Object] for Order History.

[image]

As for the datatables, it return the value that I wanted.

[image]

Here's my code: [LIVE JS BIN DEMO](https://live.datatables.net/yalesali/4/edit)

The Server_Processing.php JSON

```
 {
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 238633,
  "recordsFiltered": 183514,
  "data": [
    [
      "6789",
      "North City"
    ],
    [
      "5325",
      "South City"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Output console.log(result) for fetch_total.php ajax call

```
{"data":[[6]]}
{"data":[[1]]}
```

Basically I've pass the ID_No value to ajax call, and it will return the readable value to the cell.

I've tried by using JSON.stringify to the additionalData, it still return [object Object] value when I export as CSV file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which also includes some relevant sample data.

Comment: @andrewJames Hello. I've update. Can you take a look

Comment: You're making a separate Ajax call for each row of your data in order to populate the Order History column? Surely there is a more efficient way to get all the data you need in a single request?

Comment: @mark_b I'm making separate ajax call because first and second ajax call was from different database. The solution that I can thinking of is by using separate ajax call. I'm using SSP Class PHP because it's large dataset. Do you have suggestion how to make the data request more efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

The simplest way to fix this is to add an `exportOptions` section to your DataTable `buttons` option.

So, instead of this:

```js
buttons: [ 'csv' ],
```

you can use this:

```js
buttons: [
  {
    extend: 'csv',
    exportOptions: {
      format: {
        body: function ( inner, rowidx, colidx, node ) {
          return node.innerText;
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
```

And you can repeat the `{ extend: ... }` section for additional buttons (e.g. Excel).

This logic ensures you take the value loaded into the DOM node (the HTML table cell) instead of the value stored in the DataTable (an object).

---

**Explanation**

In your logic, you are using this:

```js
"createdCell": function(cell, cellData, rowData, rowIndex, colIndex) { ... }
```

This is documented [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell).

The key point is:

> cell: The TD node that has been created.

In other words, this `<td>` element is what you see displayed in the web page - the HTML. It is *not* what is stored in the underlying DataTable (which is the `createdCell` function used to create the contents of that `<td>` element).

So, when you try to export your data, DataTables will use the data it has stored in its internal data structures. It does not use the data *you* added to the HTML table.

My `exportOptions` function solves that by telling DataTables to look at the data in the HTML table directly (`node.innerText`) instead of using its internal data.

---

This is a very basic solution. It looks in *every* `<td>` cell in the HTML table, not just the third column. In your case, this is probably fine. But you may need to refine this, if there are other cases where you do *not* want to use the cell contents.

Also, I agree with the comments made in the question by @mark_b:

> You're making a separate Ajax call for each row of your data in order to populate the Order History column? Surely there is a more efficient way to get all the data you need in a single request?

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and answer. It's working. I'm making separate ajax call because first and second ajax call were from different database. The solution that I can thinking of is by using separate ajax call. I'm using SSP Class PHP because it's large dataset. Do you have suggestion how to make the data request more efficient way?

Comment: Glad the problem is resolved. If the data comes from 2 separate databases, you could still run 2 queries in your server-side PHP code and merge the results. That might be more efficient than fetching records one at a time from every browser using the DataTable. Just an idea - I don't know if that would be better or not.